Node-red read values of several sliders
I'm new to node-red, I need to read the values of those sliders, they have topics with the name 'age', 'weight', 'height' and 'sex' (boolean).
I don't know why but the JS function reads the values of all the sliders as undefined. I also tried adding a join node creating a key/value object with the topics but it says this:
"Message missing key property 'msg.topic' - cannot add to object"

The function is the following
function calorieCount(msg) {

    var weight, height, sex, age;
    
    node.warn("Debugging msg: " + JSON.stringify(msg));

    var weight = msg.payload;
    if (msg.topic === "weight") {
        weight = parseFloat(msg.payload);
        node.warn("Valore peso: " + weight);
    }

    if (msg.topic === "height") {
        height = parseFloat(msg.payload);
        node.warn("Valore altezza: " + height);
    }

    if (msg.topic === "sex") {
        sex = msg.payload === "true";
        node.warn("Valore sesso: " + sex);
    }

    if (msg.topic === "age") {
        age = parseInt(msg.payload, 10);
        node.warn("Valore età: " + age);
    }

    if (weight !== undefined && height !== undefined && sex !== undefined && age !== undefined) {
        node.warn("Tutti i valori sono presenti");

        var v = 0;

        if (age >= 20 && age <= 29) {
            v = (sex) ? 1.36 : 1.34;
        } else if (age >= 30 && age <= 39) {
            v = (sex) ? 1.43 : 1.34;
        } else if (age >= 40 && age <= 49) {
            v = (sex) ? 1.43 : 1.39;
        } else if (age >= 50 && age <= 59) {
            v = (sex) ? 1.43 : 1.31;
        } else if (age >= 60 && age <= 69) {
            v = (sex) ? 1.34 : 1.24;
        } else if (age >= 70 && age <= 79) {
            v = (sex) ? 1.26 : 1.13;
        } else if (age >= 80 && age <= 89) {
            v = (sex) ? 0.97 : 0.94;
        }

        var result = 0.035 * weight + ((v * v) / height) * 0.029 * weight;

        return { payload: result };
    } else {
        node.warn("Valori mancanti! Verifica: weight, height, sex, age");
        return { payload: "Error: Missing values" };
    }
}

return calorieCount(msg);

The nodes are the followings


You've not told us what the error is. Also each input message will only contain the value from 1 slider (the one that changed), you will need to cache them all before trying to do something.

@hardillb sorry, the values are read as undefined, added to the question. I also tried with a join, making everything a key/value object

You will need to configure a topic in each of the slider nodes.
